# How to check whether file exist or not in given URL?

Tags: php, laravel

How to check whether file exist or not in given URL? I can't verify that the file is found or not in a given URL:

```
$url = "https://content.gomasterkey.com/images/watermark.aspx?imageurl=/uf/1002/property/43644/581330_Image.JPG&width=640&group=1575&amp;module=1&watermarktype=default&position=TopRight";

if(file_exists($url)){
    echo "exist";
}else{
    echo "not exist";
}
if(file_get_contents($url)){
    echo "exist";
}else{
    echo "not exist";
}
```

Comment: Try `$headers = get_headers(url); stripos($headers[0],"200 OK") ? "Exist" : "Not found"`

Comment: basically i get data from gomasterkey api..the api don't permission to get headers.it give an server error "Server Error in '/' Application."
https://content.gomasterkey.com/images/watermark.aspx?imageurl=/uf/1002/property/43644/581330_Image.JPG&width=640&group=1575&amp;module=1&watermarktype=default&position=TopRight

Comment: Do you have a working url which is accessible? Your provided URL returns `500 Server exception` and stack trace says the end point returned `404 Not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to check either file exists or not.

```
$url = "https://content.gomasterkey.com/images/watermark.aspx?imageurl=/uf/1002/property/43644/581330_Image.JPG&width=640&group=1575&amp;module=1&watermarktype=default&position=TopRight";

// Open for reading only.

if(@fopen($url, 'r') ){
  
  echo  'File Found';
    
}else{
    echo 'file not found';   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usinge `fopen()` function you can check the remote file exists or not.

```
// Remote file url
$remoteFile = 'https://content.gomasterkey.com/images/watermark.aspx?imageurl=/uf/1002/property/43644/581330_Image.JPG&width=640&group=1575&amp;module=1&watermarktype=default&position=TopRight';

// Open file
$handle = @fopen($remoteFile, 'r');

// Check if file exists
if(!$handle){
    echo 'File not found';
}else{
    echo 'File exists';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [get_headers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php), because its less overhead for just checking if a file exists

```
   $headers=get_headers($url);
   if(stripos($headers[0],"200 OK")){
     echo "file exists";
   } else {
     echo "file doesn't exists";
   }
```